# Plist StartCalendarInterval not working but Start Interval does

Tags: macos, automation, plist

I'm setting up plist files to run a python script daily at 9am with plist.

When the file contains StartInterval and set 10 as int it works well and runs every 10s.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.gmtwitter.gm</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/marc/mambaforge/envs/main_env/bin/python</string>
        <string>/Users/marc/code/automation/twitter/twitter.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However when I replace it by StartCalendarInterval, the file never runs. I followed doc and tutorials but can't find why it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.gmtwitter.gm</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/marc/mambaforge/envs/main_env/bin/python</string>
        <string>/Users/marc/code/automation/twitter/twitter.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>18</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>57</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```